# How can a regular (breaking) space be added between items rendered using ng-container and ngFor in Angular to allow word wrapping

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-container

When rendering html anchor tags in an ng-container using ngFor, spaces between the tags are removed. The result is that the contents overflow the parent container.

I've tried adding a space inside a span and have used &#32; but these get removed on rendering.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tag of tags">
    <a [innerHTML]="tag"></a>
    <span>&#32;</span>
</ng-container>
```

The only way I've found is to add a space and another character (eg | pipe) and to style that as transparent so not visible.

```
<span class="wrap-hack"> |</span>
```

CSS

```
.wrap-hack {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Although that works, the breaking space allows word wrapping, it's a bit of a hack. Is there a "correct" way?

**Result without the hack**

[image]

**Result with hack**

[image]

Comment: Can you add a link to a plunker or stackblitz demonstrating what is happening and possibly what you'd like to see?

Comment: @JeffryHouser - I'm just getting black screen from Stackblitz right now, but I've added images showing result with and without the hack

Comment: Why don't you use plain CSS and make the parent a flex container with flex-wrap set to wrap? Does that make any sense?

Comment: I bet if you put the ngFor on a div; or put a div inside the ngFor then you won't have a problem.  Or put some CSS Margin on the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by default, Angular is removing the whitespace. To prevent that, add the preserveWhitespaces component decorator.

This [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-preserve-whitespace) shows the hack which is not needed with preserveWhitespaces.

[Angular Reference](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preservewhitespaces)